# Android Jetpack Compose + OKHttp

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In trying to use Jetpack Compose with OKHttp, I'm making an HTTP Request, and when it returns if there's a success I want to start a new activity otherwise show the user a toast error message.

However, I'm unsure of how to actually `startActivity`. I get the following error(s):

```
fun performLogin(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel, context: Context) {
    try {
        val email = loginViewModel.email.value
        val password = loginViewModel.password.value

        val client = OkHttpClient()

        val serverUri = SystemService.getAPIUri()
        val loginUri = "$serverUri/login"

        val data = """
            "email": "$email",
            "password": "$password"
            """.trimIndent()

        val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
            .add("email", email.toString())
            .add("password", password.toString())
            .build()

        val body = data.toRequestBody("application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull())

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(loginUri)
            .post(formBody)
            .build()

        val call = client.newCall(request)

        call.enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                response.use {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

                    for ((name, value) in response.headers) {
                        println("$name: $value")
                    }

                    println(response.body!!.string())

                    Looper.prepare()

                    // Gives an error here
                    loginCallback()

                    Looper.loop()

                }
            }

        })
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Login Error: ")
        println(e)

        val toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Error Logging In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        toast.show()
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun loginCallback() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    context.startActivity(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java))
}
```

If there's an HTTP error the toast will crash saying I have to run it in the Main Thread.

And calling loginCallback() won't work, as it says `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

Comment: Please provide example on GitHub with this problem - it is less likely that you will get any answer because many parts of code are missing such as: layouts, viewmodel, activity, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As onResponse is outside of composable, declare `val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()` outside of .enqueue(...) and launch desired code within `coroutineScope.launch { }`, same goes for Toast.makeText(...).

Answer (score 0):

Try update some state in ViewModel and in onResponse, then will trigger UI update

or

Try use function as parameter in Kotlin, pass the toast function in ViewModel to OKHttp client and use the function as callback in onResponse or onFailure

```
Inside ViewModel,
        displayToast(msg:String){
            ....
        }
        updateState(value:Boolean){
            ....
        }
        fun performLogin(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel, context: Context, displayToast: (String) -> Unit, updateState: (Boolean) -> Unit){
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                OKHttp.performLogin(loginViewModel, context, displayToast, updateState)
            }
        }


 Inside OKHttp   
    fun performLogin(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel, context: Context, displayToast: (String) -> Unit, updateState: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
           ....
    
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            displayToast("Msg you want to display")
            updateState(true)
        }
    
    }
```